# OpenGL doesn't create window with the desired size

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

So I have this code

```cpp
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Hello Triangle", NULL, NULL);
glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);
```

But, when I created a triangle with coordinate (-1, -1), (0, 1), and (1,-1), it only drew a small triangle at the corner. If I resize the window, it draws the correct triangle.

So, I set a frame buffer size callback:

```cpp
void FramebufferSizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    cout << width << " " << height << endl;
}
```

I tried to resize the window a little, and it turns out the the window size is bigger than 1024 x 768.

So, why doesn't the `glfwCreateWindow` function create a window with size 1024 x 768? Or am I having a wrong understanding?

I am using macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call of `glViewport` won't work, because at this point there  is no current OpenGL context. Call [`glfwMakeContextCurrent`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__context.html#ga1c04dc242268f827290fe40aa1c91157) to make the context of the window current, **before** any OpenGL instruction:

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Hello Triangle", NULL, NULL);

glfwMakeContextCurrent(wnd); // <-- make the context current before glViewport

glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);
```

Note, [`glfwCreateWindow`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344) creates a window and an associated OpenGL context, but it does not change which context is current.